How to deploy streamlit application in azure web app
my docker file contains are below:

FROM python:3.10.11
WORKDIR /app
COPY . .
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt
EXPOSE 8000
# Command to run the app
 


but when I try to run docker container in port 8000, it runs in 8501 as shown in below:
docker build -t streamlit-meetingsumeriserqa:1.0 .
docker images
REPOSITORY                     TAG       IMAGE ID       CREATED         SIZE
streamlit-meetingsumeriserqa   1.0       973c4ae49cd6   5 minutes ago   8.72GB
docker run -p 8000:8000 streamlit-meetingsumeriserqa:1.0
 
Collecting usage statistics. To deactivate, set browser.gatherUsageStats to false.
 
 
  You can now view your Streamlit app in your browser.
 
  Local URL: http://localhost:8501
  Network URL: http://172.17.0.2:8501
  External URL: http://49.37.72.174:8501

also in web browser, it is not opening at localhost:8501, so do we need to change any port or something.

also when I try to push docker container into azure container registry , by following quick start in portal itself. but when try to provide username and password it gives me client timeout error. as shown in below:
docker login meetingsummeriser.azurecr.io
Username: meetingsummeriser
Password:
Error response from daemon: Get "
https://meetingsummeriser.azurecr.io/v2/":
net/http: request canceled while waiting for connection (Client.Timeout exceeded while awaiting headers)

also our web app supports CORS for that we are using:
python -m streamlit run Login.py --server.port 8000 --server.address 0.0.0.0 --server.enableCORS=false --server.enableXsrfProtection=false

apart from above issue, just wanted to know as streamlit runs on port 8501 but azure web app supports port 8000, so what code changes I have to do?
As I am new to this any help will be thankful.

If Possible, share your code which you have tried.

Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.  Can you [edit] the question to replace the screen shots of error output with plain text?

The python -m streamlit run command you show is substantially different from the Dockerfile CMD, how are you invoking that command?

@AsleshaKantamsetti, I have replaced screenshots with the code.

@DavidMaze, I have replaced screenshots with the code and also updated my docker file. and passing python -m streamlit run in the startup command in web app

@Pam If you want to run the app locally with docker image docker run - p 8501:8000 :tag

@Pam az acr login -n  this is the command to push your image to Azure App Registration.

@AsleshaKantamsetti, I run this docker run -p 8501:8000 streamlit-meetingsumeriserqa:1.0, but its not opening in web browser.

@Pam You have only expose port of the container as 8000 but the command to run the streamlit you have not mentioned the port. so the application is running on the default port which is 8501. you need to mention this in command CMD ["streamlit", "run", "app.py", "--server.port=8000", "--server.address=0.0.0.0"] to listen in port 8000. and to run the docker container you need to use docker run -p <any local port>:8000 streamlit-meetingsumeriserqa:1.0

Check the below steps to deploy streamlit app to Azure app service using Azure Container Registry and Docker.
Thanks @docs.streamlit.io for the explanation.

I tried  sample Code from this Documentation

In CMD I defined the port where I want to run app.


Dockerfile:
FROM python:3.12
WORKDIR /app
COPY requirements.txt /app/
RUN pip install --no-cache-dir -r requirements.txt
COPY . /app/
EXPOSE 8000
CMD ["streamlit", "run", "app.py", "--server.port=8000", "--server.address=0.0.0.0"]

In requirements.txt you need to add streamlit package.
streamlit

In Docker Run command you can define Any local port which you want to map with docker port.
By using below commands, I build and run the docker Image locally.
docker build -t <ImageName> .
docker run -d -p <LocalPort>:<HostPortInDocker>  <ImageName>

Local Output:


In Azure Container Registry you need to Enable Admin user for Authorization.


I used below Commands to push My local image to Azure Container Registry.
az acr login --n<AzureContainerRegistryName>.azurecr.io
docker tag <ImageName> <AzureContainerRegistryName>.azurecr.io/<ImageName>:<tag>
docker push <AzureContainerRegistryName>.azurecr.io/<ImageName>:<tag>


While Creating  Azure Web app I selected Container as publish option and Clicked Next:Container button as shown below.




Make sure you're defined port is same as the port which is used in CMD in docker file.


Azure App Service Output:


@Pam Please check if the above solution helped you. Let me know if there's anything else I can assist with.
